# Is it a mold in my scoby?

Tags: vinegar, mold, apples, kombucha

For the fist time in my life I make a apple cider vinegar and don't know anything about mold in the scoby. What I know is there is a mother that will formed in there process but I don't know if its had a whiteish thing on top of it. Is it a mold or its just normal?

[image: day 5 of apple cider vinegar]

If it's a mold, how can I remove them?
fyi its been 5 days since I started the process

Answer (score 1):

This does in fact look like mold.  I would recommend removing the scoby and letting it continue to ferment.  If it returns quickly, you may need to toss this batch and start again.

You could remove the scoby by skimming with a sieve or you could pour the liquid out of this container and use something(clean hand) or sieve to catch the scoby.  The first option is probably best.

Have you been covering the container with some kind of cheese cloth or breathable lid?  In general, that is recommended as it will catch most stuff floating through air, allowing your ferment to develop more safely.

Comment: I am covering the container with a breathable lid, but I need to frequently open it to take the data, like pH and image every single day. is there any safe way to do so?

Comment: It shouldn’t be an issue to open it up for testing, just make sure your hands are clean.  What’s your pH down to at this point?

Comment: Any updates on how the project is going?